# MVC View User Control with JavaScript. How implement popup?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, user-controls, ascx

I have a small project which I have a page with a drop-down menu.  When the drop-down is selected a user control should popup.

This is an image of what I'm hoping to acomplish:
[image]

I have a .ascx file which needs to be loaded.  Where would the entry point be added to have this control pop-up? 
Here is the implementation. I have started with. This project is not using the code behind and is instead using javascript to implement controls.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<AdministratorConsole.Models.TaskActionController.TaskActionViewModel>" %> 
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!-- Some Funtions -->
</script>
<div class="main_popup_container">
<div class="task-action-header">Action Type: Hyperlink PDFs</div>
<div class="task-configuration-header">Configuration<span id="HyperlinkCopyTestResults" class="one-line-test-results"></span></div>
```

I have started a method to try to get this .ascx to pop up from the root folder without any luck. What do I need to get this MVC view user control to popup
and execute?

```
class PageLoad : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Load control from file 
        Control load = (Control)Page.LoadControl(@"~/PDFHyperlink.ascx");
    }
}
```

I also have a Interface which has and Execute GetName and TestConfiguration to run some test on user inpute and execute my code to hyperlink PDFs.

```
public bool Execute(TaskActionConfig action, TaskActionAPI.Task t, out string message)
    {
        message = GetName();
        string configMessage = "Test Message";
        bool result = TestConfiguration(action, out configMessage);
        // Run hyperlinking tool. 
        HyperlinkingTool(t);

        return true;
    }

    // **************************GetName**************************
    public string GetName()
    {
        string HyperlinkPDFs = "Hyperlink PDFs";
        return HyperlinkPDFs;
    }

    // **************************TestConfiguration**************************
    public bool TestConfiguration(TaskActionConfig action, out string message)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> parameter = action.Parameters;
        bool result = true;
        message = "Config Message";
        return result; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method GetName() needs to return the same name as the .ascx file.  This will register the .ascx file and load it.